# XML Not Sent To Client Through Response Object Correctly In IE

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml

I have an upload control that calls a handler from the client and is to send back a string of xml to the client. The code below works fine in chrome but is sending weird xml back to the client in IE.

Handler Code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var uploadInfo = context.Request.Files[0];
        var uploadStream = uploadInfo.InputStream;
        var upload = new byte[uploadInfo.ContentLength];
        uploadStream.Read(upload, 0, uploadInfo.ContentLength);
        var payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(upload);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(payload);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        context.Response.Write(doc.OuterXml);

        //context.Response.Write(payload);
    }        
}
```

The XML string debugged from handler before sent to client (which looks correct)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
 <ApplicationData>
 <DataElement name="Comments" type="String"></DataElement> 
 <DataElement name="ModAuthor" type="String"></DataElement>  
 <DataElement name="CreateDate" type="Datetime"></DataElement>    
 <DataElement name="Author" type="String"></DataElement>   
 <DataElement name="StatusDate" type="Datetime"></DataElement>  
 <DataElement name="StatusDisp" type="String"></DataElement>   
 <DataElement name="Status" type="Number"></DataElement>   
 <DataElement name="Approved" type="Number"></DataElement> 
 <DataElement name="Submitted" type="Number"></DataElement>  
 <DataElement name="LogNumber" type="Number"></DataElement>  
 </ApplicationData>
```

Then XML string that is being sent back is:

```
<DIV class=e><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;?</SPAN><SPAN class=pi>xml version="1.0" </SPAN><SPAN class=m>?&gt;</SPAN> </DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em" class=c><A class=b onfocus=h() onclick="return false" href="#">-</A> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>ApplicationData</SPAN><SPAN class=m>&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Comments</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>ModAuthor</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>CreateDate</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Datetime</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Author</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>StatusDate</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Datetime</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>StatusDisp</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Status</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Number</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Approved</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Number</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Submitted</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Number</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN class=t>ApplicationData</SPAN><SPAN class=m>&gt;</SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

For some reason from the XML is getting translated to the client in a totally different format.

Comment: Did you try different versions of IE? On different machines also? I pulled this code and IE9 is showing correct XML for me with your code. I just changed it to use a string (into a stream and converted to a byte[] array) instead of a file. I was thinking it might be an encoding issue, it may still be - will try with a file upload.

Comment: Can you post the actual payload source file you are uploading in this example? I cannot reproduce this error -- I either get an error on doc.LoadXml due to encoding, or if I change code to use XmlDocument.Load(uploadInfo.InputStream) directly, it works in IE9 and Chrome; If you can post original file I can look at it and see if I can reproduce your error and try to find a fix.

Comment: I am working with IE8, the xml above is the original file

Comment: I understand it's the original XML... I was asking for the original file (i.e., as an attachment or download) to see if it's encoded differently, has a different MIME type, etc. When I make my own XML file with your XML, I am not using the file you have. Maybe it's a non-issue but I was thinking it might be an encoding issue of some sort, which I have seen before with IE.

Comment: how can I add the original file?

Comment: You can post it somewhere (google drive, SkyDrive, your web server) and post a link to it. Best to zip it up, also.

Comment: I have no access to those types of things. Is it straight forward that i could check the MIME type and give you the results? I am not sure how

Comment: The "translated" XML looks like the formatted XML view that IE generates when you directly load an XML file without an XSL stylesheet. Are you using an `iframe` to load it?

Answer (score 2):

I have a strange feeling that this has to do with encoding, I had a similar problem once with IE.

I see in your code that you use UTF-8 encoding to get the xml as string.
Try to add the following header :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to your XML file. I know that if you leave it out it is auto-detected, but try to do this and also try to open your file with something like Notepad++ and save in UTF-8 encoding. Also, if the file is generated pragmatically, check the code and try to force UTF-8 encoding.

In my experience with web applications, the place where IE screws up (most) is where there are some default values that are different from Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc. If you do not explicitly enter these values, the browser will set it's defaults, but if you enter them in code, you will force a certain behaviour. This is not required for Chrome, Mozilla, etc. but will "fix" IE's interpretation.

One of the above mentioned default values is the encoding
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/2f5cdeff-3723-43bf-a880-d4a41222e24d/

Answer (score 0):

The "translated" XML looks like the formatted XML view that IE generates when you directly load an XML file without an XSL stylesheet. I'm guessing that your upload control is targeting a hidden `iframe`, and using the DOM to load the response.

Depending on what you're doing with the XML, you might be able to get away with forcing it to download as plain-text:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.AppendHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```

You'll need to add the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header to [prevent IE8 from trying to guess the content type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Change Following line

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

with

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```