# IE Changing Xml Through AJAX Call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am getting xml out of a file with following code..

```
var uploadInfo = context.Request.Files[0];
                var uploadStream = uploadInfo.InputStream;
                var upload = new byte[uploadInfo.ContentLength];
                uploadStream.Read(upload, 0, uploadInfo.ContentLength);
                var payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(upload);

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(payload);
```

The xml looks like this as this point as expceted..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
 <AData>
 <DataElement name="Comments" type="String"></DataElement> 
 <DataElement name="ModAuthor" type="String"></DataElement>  
 <DataElement name="CreateDate" type="Datetime"></DataElement>    
 <DataElement name="Author" type="String"></DataElement>   
 </AData>
```

I am calling my handler with this code..

```
  $.ajaxFileUpload({

                url: 'AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
                secureuri: false,
                fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (data, status) {

                    alert(data);

                },

                error: function (data, status, e) {
                    alert(e);
                }

            }
```

In chrome everything is fine but testing in IE the success method returns the following..

```
<DIV class=e><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;?</SPAN><SPAN class=pi>xml version="1.0" </SPAN><SPAN class=m>?&gt;</SPAN> </DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em" class=c><A class=b onfocus=h() onclick="return false" href="#">-</A> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>AData</SPAN><SPAN class=m>&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Comments</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>ModAuthor</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>CreateDate</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Datetime</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=e>
<DIV style="TEXT-INDENT: -2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 1em"><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class=t>DataElement</SPAN> <SPAN class=t>name</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>Author</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=t> type</SPAN><SPAN class=m>="</SPAN><B>String</B><SPAN class=m>"</SPAN><SPAN class=m> /&gt;</SPAN> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV><SPAN class=b>&nbsp;</SPAN> <SPAN class=m>&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN class=t>AData</SPAN><SPAN class=m>&gt;</SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

Any ideas what I can do to simply return the string of xml I got from the handler code? It returns the xml fine in chrome but IE is gving me what looks to be html and styles automatically.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074431/xml-not-sent-to-client-through-response-object-correctly-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.AppendHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```